# bar graph does not render d3

Tags: html, json, d3.js, graph

I have activity tracking data I want to plot with a bar graph. Why does my bar graph don't render the rects? I can't see the mistake i made. I think I got the data structure right but I can't check at all. The data is provided with this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5b5dd1c6f31cfe8a82f235865ce3e478).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 70,
      left: 40
    },
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse;
  var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    //.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"));

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  d3.json("data/testdata.json", function(data) {



    x.domain(d3.extent(data.dataset, function(d) {
      return parseDate(d.time);
    }));
    // x.domain(d3.map(data.dataset, function(d) {
    //   console.log(d.time);
    //     return parseDate(d.time)
    // }));
    // y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d, i) {
    //     return d.dataset[i].steps;
    // }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data.dataset, function(d) {
      return d.steps;
    })]);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      // .text("Time")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Steps");

    svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return x(parseDate(d.dataset[i].time));
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return y(d.dataset[i].steps);
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return width / d.dataset.length
      })
      .attr("height", function(d, i) {
        return height - y(d.dataset[i].steps);
      });

  });
</script>
```

Can you give me a hint? Do I have to nest/structure my json in another way? It must be basic but somehow I don't get the bar graphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1nujczwh/11/

First of all your dataset was wrong

```
svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
```

Should've been

```
svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data.dataset)
```

Other than that your x, y and other attributes need some work. Like:

```
return x(parseDate(d.dataset[i].time));
```

Should be

```
return x(parseDate(d.time));
```

since d3 is already looping through your data, you don't need to select them with array[index]

Since all steps was 0 I don't know what you were expecting to see so I've changed some data as an example.

I suggest putting a `console.log(d);` (I also already did that for you)  inside your attributes to see what your data is.